# Xamarin Forms MasterDetail Page Not Working on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app setup and I have been testing it with Android pretty successfully but now I am trying to add in iOS and it doesn't seem to work at all.

I have a MasterDetailPage that I mostly copied from the mobileCRM project which works fine for me on Adroid and my buildhost but not in my ported over version.

```
public class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    OptionItem _previousItem;

    public RootPage()
    {
        var optionsPage = new MenuPage { Icon = "Icon.png", Title = "menu" };

        optionsPage.Menu.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => NavigateTo(e.SelectedItem as OptionItem);

        Master = optionsPage;

        NavigateTo(optionsPage.Menu.ItemsSource.Cast<OptionItem>().First());
    }

    void NavigateTo(OptionItem option)
    {
        if (_previousItem != null)
            _previousItem.Selected = false;

        option.Selected = true;
        _previousItem = option;

        var displayPage = PageForOption(option);
        Detail = new NavigationPage(displayPage)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Helpers.Color.Orange.ToFormsColor()
        };

        Detail.SetValue(TitleProperty, option.Title);
        Detail.SetValue(IconProperty, option.Icon);

        IsPresented = false;
    }

    static Page PageForOption(OptionItem option)
    {
        switch (option.Title)
        {
            case "Home":
                return new HomePage();
            case "Circles":
                return new CirclesPage();
            case "Settings":
                return new SettingsPage ();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown menu option: " + option.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain "Not Working" ? does it crash ? does it renders badly ?

Comment: The Title Bar does not have any text and the inner content is blank. basically all you see is a blank bar at the top and you can slide out the menu and click the links but the Detail just stays a blank white page. I set a breakpoint and it never hit my page constructor.

Comment: I can confirm the issue, investigating. It's related to having a NavigationPage as MD.Detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `Xamarin.Forms`, and I've reported it.

I was able to reproduce your issue, but also able to workaround it by replacing the `ListView` in `OptionPage` by a `StackLayout` of `Buttons` :

```cs
public MenuPage (MasterDetailPage mdpage)
{
    Content = new StackLayout {
        Children = {
            new Button { Text = "Home", Command = new Command (() => {mdpage.Detail = new HomePage ();mdpage.IsPresented = false;}) },
            new Button { Text = "Circles", Command = new Command (() => {mdpage.Detail = new CirclesPage ();mdpage.IsPresented = false;}) },
            new Button { Text = "Settings", Command = new Command (() => {mdpage.Detail = new SettingsPage ();mdpage.IsPresented = false;}) },
        }
    };
}
```

In one of my projects, I'm using a TableView in the `Master`, but just like the `ListView` here, it triggers the issue.

Comment: I investigated it. not a Xamarin.Forms bug as I got it working. the issue was missing icons.

Comment: I'm running in to a similar issue where I get a blank MasterDetailPage with no header title or icon showing, even though I have those set in the ContentPage of Master.  I am also using a TableView inside Master. Could you elaborate on the missing icons issue you mentioned?